# How do I call the split function in awk to split a string on "\."?

Tags: bash, awk

How do I use  the `split` function to split by "\."?

For example, first consider splitting by `:`:

```
echo "03:26:12" | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'
```

Which produces this output:

```
122603
```

But if the incoming string is instead:

```
echo "03\.26\.12" | awk '{split($0,a,???); print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'
```

With desired output:

```
122603
```

What should the `???` be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must escape both characters:

```
echo "03\.26\.12" | awk '{split($0,a,/\\\./); print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'
```

Result:

```
122603
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "03\.26\.12" | awk '{split($0,a,"\\\."); print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'
```

This gives the same output.

Comment: does not work for me. output is: 1226\03\. plus there's a warning: `awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence '\.' treated as plain '.'`